# Limite de itens em um dicionário

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazendo a análise de dados de uma pesquisa de autoria própria, os arquivos já estão tabulados em formato .xlsx. Uso o openpyxl.

***Minha intenção*** nesse momento é pegar o estado dos participantes + a opinião deles e jogar num dicionário.

***O problema*** é que esse dicionário está retornando apenas 26 itens de posições aleatórias.

***A solução*** que eu procuro é: criar um dicio com estados:opiniões com todos os 318 participantes da pesquisa.

Meu código:

```
estados = []
u_opiniao = []
estados_x_opiniao = {}

for rowOfCellObjects in ws['B2':'B319']:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        valorestado = str(cellObj.value)
        estados.append(valorestado)

for rowOfCellObjects in ws['J2':'J319']:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        opiniao_do_u = str(cellObj.value)
        u_opiniao.append(opiniao_do_u)

for i in estados:
    estado = i
    for i in u_opiniao:
        opscen = i
        estados_x_opiniao[estado] = opscen
```

Retorno

```
Respostas(total):  318
Total de itens no estados_x_opiniao: 26
```

Comment: Em um dicionário você não consegue criar chaves iguais com valores diferentes. O dicionário define um mapa relacional 1:1, então não será possível fazer o que desejas. Uma alternativa simples que vejo é definir o dicionário com o estado como chave e uma lista de comentários como valor.

Comment: Ótima sugestão !

Answer (score 0):

Você possui mais de uma opinião por Estado? Pois o seu código vai pegar só a última opinião de um Estado e guardar.

Para armazenar mais de uma opinião por estado, crie uma lista com os valores. Exemplo:

```
estados_x_opiniao[estado] = [] 
estados_x_opiniao[estado].append(opscen)
```